# How to play url received in Listview into youtube webview?

Tags: java, android

I developed an application that receives a YOUTUBE URL from other users and plays it in the youtube player. But I want that URL to play in youtube Webview which I have in my Application. I don't have an extensive background in android and Java. This is my third time experimenting with android. So, please help me so I can make some changes in the Onclickmethod of the listview.

Here is the code that I have for playing in the youtube application or either it will ask to choose between youtube and Google chrome.

```
scanListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                    // TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    String text = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                    // textView.setText(text);

                    String launchUrl = url.concat(getUrlMethod(text,"|"));

                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(launchUrl)); //*************************************************************
                    startActivity(browserIntent);

                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Did you created an Activity which has the webview which you want to use to play the video? Currently you are just firing an intent to use other available applications on your phone

Comment: I add the Webview which access the youtube. Can you please guide me how do I create an activity that direct request to my Webview. Thanks for your Response.

Comment: Here is a pretty good article with description how to achieve this:
https://medium.com/@soffritti.pierfrancesco/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-an-android-webview-90e4b89adf79
 You can use Youtube's Android SDK to achiebve this too: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player

Comment: I got it. I just create activity and direct the string I am getting into the Webview. Thank you.